# how can i sort a list of string date in specific format in c#

Tags: c#, linq

i need to sort my list with the following code, this is what i have tried:

```
var orderedList = dateList.OrderBy(x => DateTime.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

but since the format of my dates is: `dd mmm yyyy` the above code is not working as per expectation. does anybody know, how can i apply this format for my order by method? mmm like jan, feb and ...

Comment: If you used `DateTime` vars instead of strings, the format would not matter

Comment: Lower case m is for minutes, use uppercase M for months.

Comment: Can you add an example of the values strings in `dateList` so we can see the actual format?

Answer (score 3):

Use [ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#overloads) with specifying format

```
var orderedList = dateList.OrderBy(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x, "dd MMM yyyy", null)).ToList();
```

see [working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4NRPIf)

Comment: error. string was not recognized as a valid datetime.

Comment: Shouldn't the format string should be `"dd MMM yyyy"`? `"mmm"` isn't valid. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings). Otherwise, this should work assuming the strings are formatted '"dd MMM yyyy"'.

Comment: so, your string has different format than `dd mmm yyyy`

Comment: `mmm` is minutes, not month

Comment: I still think the format string needs a third "M". `"dd MMM yyyy"`. At the end of the question, @J.P specified that: "mmm like jan, feb...". `"dd MM yyyy"` works for `"23 02 2019"` but not `"23 feb 2019"`.